# populate bs modal form and then update mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

From a link in a table:

```
<a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-id="'.$row['ID'].'">
```

and JS on that page:

```
<script>
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var rowid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            url : 'forms/php/fetchrecord.php', //fetch records 
            data :  'rowid='+ rowid, //Pass $id
            success : function(data){
            $('.fetched-data').html(data);//Show fetched data from database
            }
        });
     });
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
 location.reload();
})
});
</script>
```

I'm sending the mysql record ID to a PHP file that populates the "fetch-data" class of an "Edit" form in a BS modal.  My issue is that on Submit, the modal is not sending any data to updaterecord.php.  The updaterecord.php works when you open the "Edit" form in a new window rather than a modal.  What am I not doing or doing wrong?

```
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Order</h4>
      </div>

     <div class="modal-body">
          <form role="form" action="forms/php/updateorder.php"     method="post">

     <div class="fetch-data"></div>

         </div>

     <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"     id="updateorder">Submit</button>
     </div>

      </form>
         </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would guess that your `location.reload();` is happening before the form submits.

Comment: ...as long as the user has hidden the modal it seems.

Comment: Where is the code that handles the submit?

Comment: What data are you sending? Are you rendering response from AJAX call as text or in form fields?